# Identifying row signatures to satisfy uniqueness

Tags: r

Distillation of the problem into functional terms:

Given a list of values (let's use letters)

```
uniqueList <- letters[1:9]
```

and a 4 column data frame of values from that list in random combinations, some of which repeat (using `combn` here to produce a reasonable facsimile of my data, but my data comes from user entered data)

```
data <- t(combn(uniqueList,4))
```

How would I identify and select the minimum number of rows (and their indices) in that dataset such that each of the values from the list appears AT LEAST once, regardless of which of the columns it appears in?

In the actual problem I am trying to solve, I need to generate the smallest number of sample records, from real data such that I have every unique value from a list of values at least once in the 4 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works

```
#Split `data` into rows and then convert to vector
temp = do.call(c, lapply(1:NROW(data), function(i) data[i,]))

#Advance along `temp` and see if `unique` gives all elements of uniqueList
#Extract the first index where that happens
ind = which(sapply(1:length(temp), function(i) identical(unique(temp[1:i]), uniqueList)))[1]

#Divide the ind by number of column to obtain row number
myrow = ceiling(ind/NCOL(data))
myrow
#[1] 6

identical(sort(unique(as.vector(data[1:myrow,]))), uniqueList)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I think that this could absolutely cut down on my number of sample records.